# How to get the coordinates of the point that the mouse touch?

Tags: plotting

***How to get the coordinates of the point that the mouse touch?***

When my mouse touch the picture that the *Mathematica* touch ,I hope it can return the coordinates?

Comment: Right click - `Get Coordinates`?

Comment: Or `ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}]` and then: `
Dynamic[MousePosition["Graphics"]]`

Answer (score 5):

There are two options to interactively extract the pixel location. As suggested by Oska, you can right click on the image and choose `Get Coordinates`. This returns the coordinates with the origin at the lower left of the image, as if one were using a plot command. Or, you can right click on the image and choose "Get Indices`, which returns the indices in row/column form of the image with the origin at the upper left of the image, as if one indexing into a matrix. You can read about why this dual-indexing exists [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27404/reverse-after-imagedata/27423#27423).

If operating programmatically, then the command [`MousePosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MousePosition.html) accomplishes much the same thing, as suggested by Pinguin Dirk.